# Pandas DataFrame group by and save columns as json strings

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe with following schema:

import pandas as pd

```
# Create a list of data
data = [['market1', 2023, 100, 200],
        ['market2', 2022, 300, 400],
        ['market1', 2021, 500, 600],
        ['market2', 2020, 700, 800]]

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['market', 'year', 'val1', 'val2'])
```

Printout:

```
    market  year    val1    val2
0   market1 2023    100     200
1   market2 2022    300     400
2   market1 2021    500     600
3   market2 2020    700     800
```

I'd like to `groupby` `market` column and create a mapping `year`-`val1` and `year`-`val2` columns and save them as json strings. where `year` is the key and `val1` is the value.

Expected output:

```
market  val1_json                   val2_json

market1 {"2021": 500, "2023": 100}  {"2021": 600, "2023": 200}
market2 {"2020": 700, "2022": 300}  {"2020": 800, "2022": 400}
```

Note that the json is sorted `ascending` by the `year` key.

Answer (score 2):

Try groupby:

```
(df.drop(columns='market')
   .groupby(df['market'])
   .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('year').apply(lambda y: y.to_json()))
   .add_suffix('_json')
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
    market                val1_json                val2_json
0  market1  {"2023":100,"2021":500}  {"2023":200,"2021":600}
1  market2  {"2022":300,"2020":700}  {"2022":400,"2020":800}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a complex output for apply function by forming a pd.Series:

```
def get_json(group):
    return pd.Series({
        'val1_json': {row['year']: row['val1'] for _, row in group.iterrows()},
        'val2_json': {row['year']: row['val2'] for _, row in group.iterrows()}
    })

df \
    .groupby('market') \
    .apply(get_json)
```

Output:

```
                      val1_json               val2_json
market                                                 
market1  {2023: 100, 2021: 500}  {2023: 200, 2021: 600}
market2  {2022: 300, 2020: 700}  {2022: 400, 2020: 800}
```